# Exporting from pgadmin reads line breaks in field cells and creates unreadable Excel

Tags: line-breaks, export-to-csv, pgadmin

I'm new to this, so I am sure it is a silly question, but I have read through every question related on the site and can't find anything!

I am exporting from pgadmin. A few of the columns have line breaks within the cells, so the exported data is very choppy. Does anyone know how to fix this? Is there a way to make it so the line breaks within cells are not read?

I know I am doing the right settings for exporting, but basically what happens is that the header names are  there, along with one row of content for each column and then Column A will have 20 more rows beneath it because of line breaks from the first cell in column E.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you're referring to the *Query* --> *Execute to file* command in the Query window. I don't think it's a bug that pgAdmin doesn't escape line breaks within strings in its csv output, but Excel can read it correctly anyway.

In the export options, please make sure that you use **commas** as column separators and **double quotes** as quote chars. Here are my settings:
[image: pgAdmin execute to file settings]

Additionally, when you load your CSV into Excel, please **don't** use *Data* -> *From Text*. This one doesn't parse CSV with line breaks correctly. Just open the file directly in Excel (via *Open* within Excel, or by right clicking it in Windows Explorer and choosing *Open With* -> *Microsoft Excel*).